# How to get only mp3 links using beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**This is my Code :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.djmaza.info/Abhi-Toh-Party-Khubsoorat-Full-Song-MP3-2014-Singles.html")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
    if re.findall('http',a['href']):
        print ("URL:", a['href'])
```

Output Of this code :

```
URL: http://twitter.com/mp3khan
URL: http://www.facebook.com/pages/MP3KhanCom-Music-Updates/233163530138863
URL: https://plus.google.com/114136514767143493258/posts
URL: http://www.djhungama.com
URL: http://www.djhungama.com
URL: http://songs.djmazadownload.com/music/Singles/Abhi Toh Party (Khoobsurat) -190Kbps [DJMaza.Info].mp3
URL: http://songs.djmazadownload.com/music/Singles/Abhi Toh Party (Khoobsurat) -190Kbps [DJMaza.Info].mp3
URL: http://songs.djmazadownload.com/music/Singles/Abhi Toh Party (Khoobsurat) -320Kbps [DJMaza.Info].mp3
URL: http://songs.djmazadownload.com/music/Singles/Abhi Toh Party (Khoobsurat) -320Kbps [DJMaza.Info].mp3
URL: http://www.htmlcommentbox.com
URL: http://www.djmaza.com
URL: http://www.djhungama.com
```

I need only .mp3 links .

So , How should I rewrite the code ?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `findAll` to use a regex to do the matching, eg:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile('http.*\.mp3')):
    print ("URL:", a['href'])
```

Update relating to comment:

> I need to store those links on an array for downloading . how can i do that ?

You can build a list using a list-comprehension instead:

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('http.*\.mp3'))]
```

Comment: @MuneebK You're welcome. On a side note, as you're using `bs4` - you might want to use `.find_all` instead of `findAll` as the later was BS3 style and is being kept for backwards compatibility, but may be removed at some point - so best to get into the habit of using the `something_something` functions instead of the `somethingSomething` ones.

Comment: I need to store those links on an array for downloading . how can i do that ?

Comment: Thanks again . :)  really new to Python and beautifulSoup . Doing a project for college . A mass Downloader for Linux , which helps to download multiples files  like mp3 , jpg etc .. so ur suggestions will be helpful for me:D

Answer (score 2):

You could use [.endswith()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). For instance:

```
if re.findall('http',a['href']) and a['href'].endswith(".mp3"):
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!. It helped me a lot. I'd like to translate this article to share with my Korean friends. It will be posted [here ctrlaltdel](http://ctrlaltdel.co.kr/) Please let me know if you mind it. then I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If only the extension interests you then you must know that `endswith()` returns a boolean value not the extension of the file. It is better to build your own function for this purpose like this:

```
if re.findall('http',a['href']) and isMP3file(a['href'])):
```

Now you can define the function this way:

```
import os
def isMP3file(link):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(link)
    return ext.lower() == '.mp3'
```